# SSRS Subreport or other solution

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I am working on a report that will show scheduling data. This report will need to show data for any job that has a promised date between a specified date range.

The issue I am running into is how to best display this data, I have a dataset built that has header info (Job #, Description, Due Date etc.) which returns a single line row for each job.

There are then several detail records for each job (Line item descriptions / details, Work center descriptions and details). Each of these could return several rows.

My question is how to group this detail data with each header record. Hoping to have something like this with one record block per job:

-- Header Dataset Job Number , Job Desc, Date Ship By ... etc. 
   --Line item description dataset
   --Work Center dataset

Next record.....

Thanks in advance for any help.

Brian

Answer (score 2):

If each of the records in your dataset have a field that they can be grouped by then this is actually pretty easy.  You need to use the grouping feature of the table in SSRS.  It's easiest to create a view that contains all the rows (both headers and details) logically and pass it to SSRS as one dataset.

Here is a recent walkthrough from Microsoft.  You can change the version number to match your specific version since you didn't specify in the question.  Group header fields can be formatted distintly to make them standout etc.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx

If a field that you can group by isn't contained in the dataset in the report, i.e. it's a foreign relationship or something and you can't put them into a single view then you'll need to look into sub-reports.  Based on the information provided however a simple row or column group should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. Sorry I should have mentioned that we are using SSRS 2008.